# PNG: importing it with latex | pdflatex | xelatex

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdftex, scaling

I never understood how `(pdf)latex` determines the size of imported bitmaps, but many years ago I experimentally elaborated simple rule that allowed me to get same output by running  either `latex` or `pdflatex` compiler over same source. By this rule, natural height and width of a PNG graphics (number of pixels in height and width) should be indicated in optional argument of `\includegraphics` suffuxed with `bp` units, e.g.,

```
\includegraphics[natwidth=162bp,natheight=227bp]{Aston.png}
```

Imported graphics can then be scaled to desired size by adding the `scale` or `width` options. Most importantly is that that the result did not depend on the resolution of PNG graphics. That rule, however, appeared to not work with `xelatex`.  Expected size (I mean the size of imported graphics produced by `latex` or `pdflatex`) is obtained only if DPI is 72. Here is my test source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
[natwidth=162bp, natheight=227bp, width=70bp]; DPI=72;\\
\fbox{\includegraphics[natwidth=162bp,natheight=227bp, width=70bp]{Aston.png}}

\medskip
[natwidth=200bp, natheight=287bp, width=70bp]; DPI=120; DPI=96; DPI=72;\\
\fbox{\includegraphics[natwidth=200bp,natheight=287bp, width=70bp]{200px-Hans_Bethe.png}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[natwidth=200bp,natheight=287bp, width=70bp]{Bethe-DPI96.png}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[natwidth=200bp,natheight=287bp, width=70bp]{Bethe-DPI72.png}}
\end{document}
```

Here is output produced by xelatex:

[image: output of xelatex]

So. I am in doubts now what to do with appendix to my book? It contains more than a hundred of bitmaps.

Comment: The size of EPS files is determined by `graphics/x` by reading the `BoundingBox` ASCII header. The size of PDF, PNG or JPG is read in binary by `pdftex` (I assume). This file formats hold the size as part of the binary header.

Comment: Sorry, Igor, I have problems to understand the problem. Could you explain why a simple `\includegraphics[width=70bp]` does not work? Modern versions of `(pdf)latex` and `graphic/x` shouldn't need `natwidth` and `natheight`.

Comment: @Martin: I use natwidth because I want the source be also suitable for latex.exe. I've check again that latex complains if natural size of png is not somehow speifiied.

Comment: @Martin: latex still cannot read size from png.

Comment: Ok, so far I was under the impression that `latex` doesn't support PNG at all. This probably changed now because it is actually `pdflatex` in DVI mode. But it is funny that it doesn't read the size of PNGs. You could use graphic rules and put the size as bounding box into `.bb` files.

Answer (score 7):

The size of EPS files is determined by `graphics/x` by reading the `BoundingBox` ASCII header. The size of PDF, PNG or JPG is read in binary by `pdftex` (I assume). This file formats hold the size as part of the binary header. For XeLaTeX it should be the same as for PDF-LaTeX, I guess.

Nowadays `latex` actually runs `pdflatex` in DVI mode. Apparently it doesn't read the size of PNGs from the files in this mode while it works well in PDF mode.
One way to do this is to create `.bb` files for all you PNGs, e.g. `foo.png.bb` for `foo.png`, which holds the line (shown here for a 200x287 bp image):

```
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 200 287
```

Then create a graphics rule for these as described in the *Graphics Guide* (`grfguide`):

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{png}{.png.bb}{}
```

You should be able to generate these files using a script automatically. You then don't need to declare the size manually using `natwidth` and `natheight` every time you use them.

However, I didn't tested this throughly. It might be not a good idea to use PNGs with `latex` at all.

Comment: PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX are diiferent in interpreting `natwidth`+`natheight` or (I guess) `bb` parameters given in options to \`includegraphics`. PDFLaTeX assumes that [natwith=72,natheight=72] stands for bitmap image of size of 72bp*72bp independantly of actual DPI encoded into the bitmat. On the contrary, XeLaTeX respects DPI. I don't know which of the two methods is more correct. The fact is that they are different.