# Image is not showing full width and height

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image from \includegraphics showing in wrong image size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/image-from-includegraphics-showing-in-wrong-image-size)

Image is not showing full width and height, it is showing 100% as single dot, when you zooming view this picture some what bigger. I also mentioned the width and height for the picture is not showing it correctly. Its always showing like this. What we do this in LaTeX? Please look at the two images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\begin{document} 
Text
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pic3}
\caption{caption text}
\label{fig:image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of image file is `pic3`? Are you compiling with `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually `\includegraphics` is used as `\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{pic3}`. 
I am not sure that LaTeX is able to get a correct size of picture for any format. E.g., jpeg image has no 'size' in dimension units at all.

Comment: Indeed, setting a width explicitly should help. Normally `pdflatex` should not have any issue with JPG and PNG images, but sometimes the resolution meta-data in such files is incorrect or not suitable.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12939/png-importing-it-with-latex-pdflatex-xelatex

Comment: working for me this url